# How do I change the url of my website in HTML

Tags: html, url

I created a website using HTML but the URL for it is http://localhost:63342/HTML-1/index.html?_ijt=msoifgevsovhi99o9bqq7kged7. No one will be able to get into my website. I want to change the URL to something like learntocode.org but I don't know how to. I use PyCharm to create my websites, so if you know a way to change it in PyCharm without code, please tell me how.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a site helping you out in this general way. The minimum requirements at SO are, that you'd post the code relevant to the issue in the question itself, and describe the problem in details. What you want your code to do, and what it does instead.

Comment: You need to read about how to set up your own website on your own server, if that's what you want. Very generally, you need (1) a domain name (purchased), (2) a (probably dynamic) DNS service, (3) a NAT table entry in your router mapping your external internet IP address and port  to your internal server IP network address. If that sounds like a lot, that's why there are:hosting services. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should read more about website deployment. Something like [this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-deploy-a-static-website-for-free-in-only-3-minutes-with-google-drive/) might suffice, or you might want to look for another way which will suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this really helped. But a problem is that every time I make changes, I have to put the files in google drive again.

Comment: This is the case even with an ordinary server. It would be a terrible practice to change a live website.